# Correlated subquery (selecting within a select) in SQLite returns error "Error: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1"

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

```
SELECT employeeId, (select 1 as first, 2 as second from 'employee') as nested
FROM 'employee'
```

returns the error in SQLite

```
Error: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1
```

The reason why I'm doing the query like is because I want the returned data structure in my Node.js app to have a nested object like so:

```
[employeeId: 123, nested: {first: 1, second: 2} }]
```

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want a json object as a column? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Can you use a simple query
SELECT *,1 as first, 2 as second from 'employee'; 
And then create a new data item from the result?
Otherwise use concatenate || to construct a string
"first:" || 1 ", || "second: " || 2

Comment: @forpas Yes, the nested column should be a json. I posted the expected results, however the sample data in this case is trivial since it can be inferred from my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can return only one column from correlated so you must convert a multi-column select into a json like so:

```
 select e.id , (select to_json(first: 1 , second: 2) from emp ee where e.id = ee.id group by ee.id) from emp e
```

replace to_json with sqlites json aggregate

however sqlite does not have the json aggregate built in so you will need to download and load it into your app. Download here: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html